# n-tier architecture with factory patterns

Tags: c#, asp.net, factory-pattern

I am new to factory patterns, i wanted to use the factory patterns in one of my project, below is the architecture i had designed for my project.

My Solution has below Projects:

1. Data - This will have Entity Framework 6, i am using Database first approach.
2. DataAccess - This will call functions from Data Project
3. Entities - This has all the entities of the Project
4. Core - This will have all the business logic and calculations.
5. ServiceInterface - This will have all the interfaces for the classes inside core project.
6. ServiceFactory - This will have class which will create Class Instance from the Core Project.

All the above projects for now have a common class called Users.

I have properties defined in Entities Project which are inherited to the Core project along with IUser interface which has methods declarations.

This is how my Entities.User class looks:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string Displayname {get; set;}
}
```

My Core.Users looks like below

```
public class Users : Entities.Users, IUsers
{
    public void Add()
    {
        //calling Data.Users function here.
    }
}
```

My Interface.Users looks like below

```
public interface IUsers
{
    void Add();
}
```

My ServiceFactory.Users looks like below

```
public class FactoryService
{
    public static IUsers CreateUserInstance()
    {
        return new Core.Users();
    }
}
```

Now in my main project i am using it like below

```
IUsers oUser = FactoryService.CreateUserInstance();
```

Now my question is, i am not able to access any Entities within my main project using above `oUser` object.

Comment: As an exercise it may be OK but in practice this is not a very good use-case for this pattern. Normally your services would be manged by the DI container.

Comment: Could you please help me to take optimum use of factory from this example?